# Module enable / disable is slow using drush cim

Tags: 8, configuration

I have 2 drupal sites which takes a high time to enable or disable modules, while other sites are faster. It is true these slow sites are more complex: it has a lot more of modules.

Is there any solution for this problem or some way to debug it?

Comment: The way to debug it would be xdebug/xhprof/etc, it's not likely you'll find tools or approaches specific to enabling/disabling modules in Drupal; bit too niche. It sounds like you've already identified a reasonable suspicion, that it's due to the number of modules, so that's where I'd concentrate my efforts if I had to do the same thing

Comment: Could also potentially have todo with the webhost/server. Are those other sites running on same specs?